# What is the char variable's encoding type?

Tags: c, char

I use sizeof() method to get the memory size of char variable. i.e.,I write such a code in Xcode:

```
    char a = '1';
size_t size = sizeof(a);
```

I find the size is 1.So what is this character's encoding type? UTF-8 or another?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996026/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-c-strings

Comment: The `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1, by definition, in C.

Comment: OT: `sizeof` isn't a method or alike, but an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` method is not enough to determine what the encoding of a character is.

In general, you must be told what encoding is being used before being able to interpret characters.

As stated in a comment, look here for some information on C string encoding: [What is the default encoding for C strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996026/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-c-strings)

Comment: No, I can't understand.  i.e.,I write this code in C, char a = '1'; is the encoding is not certained?

Comment: Your question didn't say anything about this code `char a = '1';`.

Comment: So if I write such a code,what is the encoding type?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to know this before using the character, just as you are expected to know the encoding of a string before you can interpret it correctly.

You cannot determine the encoding without prior knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For some character literals the C Standard defines a fixed value (the digits if I remembers correctly) for others (letters) the C Standard leaves it to the implementation which char-set/encoding to use.