# Output difference in C implementation of Java code

Tags: java, c, base64, pbkdf2

I am using PBKDF2 password hashing technique in my program. The sample program to which I am referring is in C.
The program snippet is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include "base64.h"

#define KEY_LENGTH      24
#define SEPARATOR       "$"
#define SALTLEN 12

#define USAGE() fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-i iterations] [-p password]\n", progname)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int iterations = 901, rc, blen;
    unsigned char   saltbytes[SALTLEN];
    char *salt, *b64;
    unsigned char key[128];
    char *pw1, *pw2, *password;
    char *progname = argv[0];
    int c;
    int prompt;

    prompt = 1;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:p:")) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'i':
                iterations = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'p':
                pw1 = strdup(optarg);
                pw2 = strdup(optarg);   
                prompt = 0;
                break;
            default:
                exit(USAGE());
        }
    }

    argc -= optind - 1;
    argv += optind - 1;

    if (argc != 1) {
        exit(USAGE());
    }

    if ( prompt ) {
        pw1 = strdup(getpass("Enter password: "));
        pw2 = getpass("Re-enter same password: ");
    }

    if (strcmp(pw1, pw2) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Passwords don't match!\n");
        return (1);
    }

    password = pw1;

    rc = RAND_bytes(saltbytes, SALTLEN);
    if (rc == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get random bytes for salt!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    base64_encode(saltbytes, SALTLEN, &salt);

#ifdef RAW_SALT
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(password, strlen(password),
        (unsigned char *)saltbytes, SALTLEN,
        iterations,
        EVP_sha256(), KEY_LENGTH, key);
#else
    int saltlen;
    saltlen = strlen(salt);

    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(password, strlen(password),
        (unsigned char *)salt, saltlen,
        iterations,
        EVP_sha256(), KEY_LENGTH, key);
#endif


    blen = base64_encode(key, KEY_LENGTH, &b64);
    if (blen > 0) {
        printf("PBKDF2$%s$%d$%s$%s\n",
            "sha256",
            iterations,
            salt,
            b64);

        free(b64);
    }

    free(password);
    return 0;
}
```

And the C program output is as follows : 
 PBKDF2$sha256$901$QLtznh6yjEs4a4Fl$**uzp3QAEpFZsqBvCssnL1eXZFxCiKzV7P**

I tried to replicate the same in Java, which is as follows:

```
public class NewPBKDF2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        String originalPassword = "A3E9907E59A6379DB6A9C2657D242A64886D5B21E3586B3D4C2B4E6329570A10";
        String generatedSecuredPasswordHash = generateStorngPasswordHash(originalPassword);
        System.out.println(generatedSecuredPasswordHash);
    }

    private static String generateStorngPasswordHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        int iterations = 901;
        char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = getSalt();
        String salt1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt);
        int length = 24;




        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterations, length * 8 );
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        byte[] hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        String hash1 = bytesToHex(hash);

        try {
            hash1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash1.getBytes("utf-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewPBKDF2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        return "PBKDF2$sha256$"+ iterations +"$"+salt1+"$"+hash1;
    }

    private static byte[] getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        byte[] salt = new byte[12];


        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

   static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
     public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

     public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

And the above program is giving me output as follows:

PBKDF2$sha256$901$v2DdYPk47r/I3aQJ$**N0Y3MjZENzVEOTE5MDcxQkNEOEM5MTAyREQ2MjdEQ0NGNzIzRTZGN0ZCOUYzN0NF**

Why I am getting different password length(the last part). I don't get it.
Can you please help me find my mistake?

Comment: what is stored in `originalPassword`(exactly) variable?

Comment: String right now hardcoded. but it will be randomly generated/.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is laid on the foundations of various **Character Encoding** styles. And the dissimilarity in length of String is because of the use of different Encoding in both cases(C and Java Implementation).

You can note in your example that the `hash1`(because of which the dissimilarity in length is prominent) variable is encoded in `UTF-8` in **Java** while the C used `ASCII` character encoding(Already mentioned in the [ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996026/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-c-strings) standards).
Also, UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding is a multi-byte encoding which uses between 1 and 4 bytes per character.
You can also refer this:[How many bytes does Unicode Character takes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take) which might be interesting and that is why the hashes are longer in length in java as compared to C.

Hope the answer helps to get some insights about the **well-researched** problem.