# Printing bytes of UTF-8 string in C

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

I wanted to print individual bytes of word "česnek" expecting to printf 7 bytes, because "č" is coded in 2 bytes, which it does but prints garbage character such as a question mark in terminal. If I print out the integer value, I get this sequence.

```
-60 -115 101 115 110 101 107
```

Why are the first two numbers negative?
Here is the code I used to try it.

```
 char *utfstring = "česnek";
 for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(utfstring); i++) {
 printf("%c ", utfstring[i]);
 }
 for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(utfstring); i++) {
 printf("%d ", utfstring[i]);
 }
```

I expected first two values to be c4 8d because č is encoded like that according to https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=dec

Comment: On some systems `char` are `signed`, on others there are `unsigned`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing UTF-8 strings with printf - wide vs. multibyte string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals)

Comment: wrt. the 'negative numbers': try "%u" for unsigned decimal.

Comment: The correct font for this character must be installed on the system and accessible to the given terminal program. On my system, it prints just fine with `printf("%s\n",utfstring);` Looping on `"%c "` will _not_ work (injecting the space _breaks_ the `utf-8` sequence). The compiler does _not_ care about this. Nor does `printf` with `%s` as it just sees a string of bytes. Only the terminal program/font will care. Better to print the individual chars with `%2.2X` to see individually [when in doubt, mask the value against `0xFF` to avoid sign extension of `char`].

Answer (score 5):

Use `(unsigned char)utfstring[i]` or `0xFF & utfstring[i]` to get hexadecimal output as follows:

```
char *utfstring = u8"česnek";
for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(utfstring); i++)
    printf("%02X ", 0xFF & utfstring[i]);
```

output:

```
"C4 8D 65 73 6E 65 6B"
```

The first alphabetic character `č` cannot be represented by a single byte in UTF8. If you print `utfstring` one byte at a time, then the UTF8 encoding is broken.

It has to be printed as `u8"č"` or `u8"\xC4\x8D"`

In general you will need a Unicode library, such as iconv, if you wish to break the byte sequence in to separate Unicode code points. If you are simply trying to find `č`, then use the standard string functions, for example `strstr(utfstring, u8"č")`.

Comment: "If you print utfstring one byte at a time, then the UTF8 encoding is broken.": Well, bytes go into the output stream one a time. Breakage would only come from the formatting functions or output stream transforming them (which for %c, I don't think would cause UTF-8 breakage),

Comment: @TomBlodget yes `printf("%c%c\n", 0xC4, 0x8D)` can work, but `printf("%c %c\n", 0xC4, 0x8D)` (with space in between) will print some ASCII characters, the latter is attempted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, the signedness of `char` is [implementation-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Character_types). On top of that, you're telling `printf()` to print a signed number by using `%d`. To portably print them as unsigned numbers, you need to cast them to `unsigned` and print them using the `%u` [format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
printf("%u ", (unsigned char) utfstring[i]);
```

That'll take care of the negative numbers, but you have another problem: the C standard does not require a compiler to accept UTF-8 encoded characters in source code. Only a [small set of basic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996026/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-c-strings) are guaranteed by the standard. You may need to check the documentation for your specific compiler and standard library to see how this is handled. You may get UTF-8, some other encoding, or garbage; and whatever you get, it isn't portable. If this sounds lame, you're right, it is - C/C++ have been playing catch-up for a long time when it comes to i18n.

The good news is, things are getting better. If your compiler supports C11, you can and should take advantage of [UTF-8 string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) to portably encode UTF-8 code points in strings.

Comment: oh, i see, i thought i'd these values "c4 8d" first, becase that is the value of č according to https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=dec

Comment: `(unsigned) utfstring[i]` will not  portably print them as desired.  `(unsigned char) utfstring[i]` makes more sense unless you want -1 as FFFFFFFF

Comment: @chux I see your point, but doesn't `%u` expect an argument of type `unsigned`, not `unsigned char` - so in this situation do we need a double cast `(unsigned) (unsigned char) utfstring[i]`?

Comment: `(unsigned char) utfstring[i]` is sufficient.  With arguments to ... (ellipsis) functions, positive `int` values must encode the same as `unsigned` per C11 §6.5.2.2 6. so using `"%u"` with `(unsigned char) utfstring[i]` is good specified functionality.,

Comment: @chux Edited, thanks. Do you happen to know if that is true pre-C11 also?

Comment: @TypeIA C99 like C11 in this regard.  As I read C89, the same applies - although less clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for`-loop iterates through the character value *byte-by-byte,* when the UTF representation is *multi-byte.*

`char *utfstring = "česnek";` is *more than six bytes long!*  Because the first "character" in that string occupies more than one byte.  (The cleverness of the UTF representation is that each of the bytes are self-encoded in such a way that, by examining the binary content of each byte alone, you can reliably determine what "kind" of byte it is, and where it falls [if applicable] in a multi-byte sequence.)

Your logic tries to use `%c` and then `%d` formats against these bytes when, arguably, neither one is most appropriate. "In this [human] context, these aren't really characters, nor are they integers." Try `%x` ... hexadecimal. *"Show me the bits."*

Comment: oh, i see, i thought i'd these values "c4 8d" first, becase that is the value of č according to https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=dec

Comment: The OP stated they expected 7 bytes and they appear to understand UTF-8. The question was _why_ the printed numbers were negative decimals instead of hex.